# How to add android-map-utils-master into eclipse without error?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am a newbie about google maps for android..

I just want to learn about this project [GoogleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock](https://github.com/ddewaele/GoogleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock), but I have a problem with installing maps-utils library, that project can't run because the maps-utils library have an trouble after I import to eclipse.

I have searched enough but I still confusing, my search stop into how install maven, because I am confused about that.

I need introduction from beginning about how to import this library without an error into eclipse.

[image]

Comment: where does it say it used map-utils? i see only actionbarsherlock

Comment: but i have an error like this, i think it because about that library..
check this out, http://prntscr.com/2aj6c4

Comment: just import the library project. its a library project.

Comment: what library?
i have import actionbarsherlock, google-play-services-libs, android support grid layout, i have done add that library, anything else to add?

i am sorry if i have much questions,iam a newbie,thank you very much

Comment: create a new project. copy everything in map-utils/library and paste in the new project folder. refresh eclipse. Mark the project as a library project. Reference the library where it is needed.

Comment: oke, thanks @Raghunandan, how to mark my new project as library?
i right click project, there's no option to save as library,

thanks very much

Comment: have you gone through the docs. pls read the docs instead of asking for everything. http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html

Comment: @Raghunandan: okay thx a lot, sorry if my question so bored for you..
i'll try...
thanks

Comment: @Raghunandan: i am sorry, it have still an error like before..

may you send me your maps-utils library?
or there're other configuration for my eclipse??

like installing maven, etc, coz my eclipse haven't maven included.

Comment: sorry this is way beyound i can help. I only can post what needs to be done and i have done that.

Comment: okay @Raghunandan, thanks for all your information before,i'll try again..

Comment: @Raghunandan: i have been download your maputils, it's work, :)
but i have new trouble when i run goglemapsv2withbarsherlock it have error like this http://prntscr.com/2bjvdm

can you help me again?

Comment: please post a new question and don't post links coz your question will be voted won.

Comment: @Raghunandan: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20607967/anyone-can-help-me-with-googlemaps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download mpa-utils from https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils

Its a Library project. Reference the library project just as would do for google play services.

[image]

Libraries used.

1. android-map utils.
2. https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip
3. ActionBarSherlock
4. googleplay services lib
5. gridlayout from /android-sdk-linux/extras/android/support/v7

Referenced all those libraries.

You might get jar mismatch. So you need to copy the latest support library to libs folder of those library projects.

Clean and build it will work

See the snap above.

Comment: i have done to download it, after i imported and i have error like this...
http://prntscr.com/2aj8iz
what must be i can do next?

Comment: @karisma have you imported `ActionbarSherLock` library?

Comment: You might have forgot to check Android SDK. Check!

Comment: @karisma what happens now?

Comment: @Raghunandan: i'm sorry to late answer,coz my connection have a trouble...

yes, i have to import actionbarsherlock...
but the project has an error like that (prntscr.com/2aj8iz)...

paresh: what must be i can do about check Android SDK? what like?
i am sorry i confused about your suggestion...

Comment: @karisma avoid posting links. pls post the error. or the code relevant. Broken link.

Comment: i'll explain about my imported this project:
1. i imported the project from github
2. i have imported three project, actionbarsherlock, googlemapsv2withactio..., and google play sevice libs, all from that rar
3. and erroring is like this http://prntscr.com/2aju2m

Comment: @karisma i can't fix it just by looking at the screen show. google search fro no resource identifier found

Comment: 4. i have import other library, like pagersliding and gridlayout v7, coz i follow about the error in project properties (look at this http://prntscr.com/2ajujd ), then the project has an error like this http://prntscr.com/2ajv9e

Comment: @karisma sorry i said i can't keep looking at the links.5. I can't help further.

Comment: what do you mean about "links.5" @Raghunandan ?

Comment: @Raghunandan: :-(, okay it's no problem, btw, have you try this project? it's work??

Comment: @karisma those errors are bcoz you have not referenced the library project. Also those red x is bcoz of broken link

Comment: @karisma i will update my post. yes the project works.

Comment: @Raghunandan: can you send me your android maps utils into my email?
karisma.pribadi@gmail.com

my problem is about maps utils library, where the library always have an error and i don't know where is the error..